# Similar structs for compiler looks same

Tags: c, visual-studio

I have 2 headers (and .c files respectively) with structures:

```
#pragma once
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct NodeInt {
    int value;
    struct NodeInt *next;
} NodeInt;

void push(NodeInt **head, int data);

int pop(NodeInt **head);

NodeInt* getNth(NodeInt* head, int n);

NodeInt* getLast(NodeInt *head);

void pushBack(NodeInt *head, int value);

NodeInt* getLastButOne(NodeInt* head);

void popBack(NodeInt **head);

void insert(NodeInt *head, unsigned n, int val);

int deleteNth(NodeInt **head, int n);

void deleteList(NodeInt **head);

void fromArray(NodeInt **head, int *arr, size_t size);

int* toArray(const NodeInt *head);

void printLinkedList(const NodeInt *head);

int length(const NodeInt *head);
```

and ListDouble.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct NodeDouble {
    struct NodeDouble *next;
    double value;
} NodeDouble;

void push(NodeDouble **head, double data);

double pop(NodeDouble **head);

NodeDouble* getNth(NodeDouble* head, int n);

NodeDouble* getLast(NodeDouble *head);

void pushBack(NodeDouble *head, double value);

NodeDouble* getLastButOne(NodeDouble* head);

void popBack(NodeDouble **head);

void insert(NodeDouble *head, unsigned n, double val);

double deleteNth(NodeDouble **head, int n);

void deleteList(NodeDouble **head);

void fromArray(NodeDouble **head, double *arr, size_t size);

double* toArray(const NodeDouble *head);

void printLinkedList(const NodeDouble *head);

int length(const NodeDouble *head);
```

Sources have are similar signature, but with difference in Double / Int respectively.
When i try to compilation, i got error that this declarations of functions are incompatible.

Is compiler think, that NodeInt and NodeDouble are sameDatatype and he don't see difference, and i should change names of functions? Or this problem has resolve?

Answer (score 1):

These functions have the same name but different signatures, such as `int length(const NodeDouble *head)` and `int length(const NodeInt *head)`.  You'll have to resolve these naming conflicts.  You could use a naming scheme such as prepending to which library they belong to avoid naming conflicts.

So you might have `int List_Int_Length(const NodeInt *head)` and `double List_Double_Length(const NodeDouble *head)`

If you want to get fancy and still use the same names when calling the functions, you can use C11's `_Generic` to select the correct operation to call.  Let us first assume that you've gone ahead and fixed the naming conflicts as above.  Now let us add a third header, ListGeneric.h:

```
#ifndef LIST_GENERIC_H
#define LIST_GENERIC_H

#include "ListInt.h"
#include "ListDouble.h"

#define length(X) _Generic((X), \
    const NodeInt *: List_Int_Length((X)), \
    const NodeDouble *: List_Double_Length((X)) \
)

#endif
```

With that it will automagically pick the right function based on the type of the object passed in.